# Run command with sudo from a graphical Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a graphical python application that can execute some external programs on Linux without showing the terminal.

First, I tried to use subprocess.run() to see if it actually works, but Python 3.7.3 shows no results to the code I wrote.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['sudo', 'apt', 'update'])
```

I changed it to see any results:

```
import subprocess
a = subprocess.run(['sudo', 'apt', 'update'])
print(a)
```

but it shows this result instantly:

```
CompletedProcess(args=['sudo', 'apt', 'update'], returncode=1)
```

This script will take at least 5 seconds to be finished, and it requires sudo privileges to be able to run it in the first place, so I don't think that Python shell executed this script.

Comment: returncode
```Exit status of the child process. Typically, an exit status of 0 indicates that it ran successfully.```

Comment: This depends on your `/etc/sudoers` file. By default, applications without a TTY aren't allowed to use sudo at all. Maybe use `gksudo`, which is explicitly intended for graphical use, instead?

Comment: In order to get subprocess to output to stdout, you have to give it arguments: `subprocess.run([...], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`. [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy, however, sudo prompts for passwords on the TTY, not via stdin/stdout, so I don't see why that would be relevant.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy For easier debugging, mostly

Comment: gksudo is deprecated since Ubuntu 18.04. The new method is pkexec. Thanks alot @CharlesDuffy for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pkexec instead of sudo fixed my issue. Thanks for everyone tried to help me especially @Charles Duffy.

Now it looks like this:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['pkexec', 'apt', 'update'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result.stdout)
```